# Page not found 404 django 3

Tags: python, html, django

I got the error **Page not found (404)** when I try to reach the 'contact.html' and 'about.html' page

I don't understand why I'm getting this.
Here is my code:

**app/urls.py:**

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.frontpage, name="frontpage"),
    path('<slug:slug>/', views.article, name="article"),
    path('contact/', views.contact, name="contact"),
    path('about/', views.about, name="about"), # If I write '/about/' that's working but the url is 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/%2Fabout/' and not 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/contact/' as i want. Same issue for contact
]
```

**app/views.py:**

```
def contact(request):
    return render(request, 'contact.html')


def about(request):
    return render(request, 'about.html')

# Of course the html file are created, they are located in the template folder
```

I'm trying to reach each page with this html code:

```
<a href="{% url 'citrouille:frontage' %}">Home</a> # This is working
<a href="{% url 'citrouille:contact' %}">Contact</a> # This is not working
<a href="{% url 'citrouille:about' %}">Aboout</a> # This is not working
```

(citrouille is my app's name)

Here is the ***mysite/urls.py*** (root folder):

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', include('citrouille.urls')),
] + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

I have others functions working perfectly such as the article page with the slug. But this two pages doesn't want to show. I'm pretty sure this is a stupid error but i can't point it.

Thank you for the help

Comment: path('<slug:slug>/', views.article, name="article"), is the problem this will map all strings and redirects to article

Comment: Move `path('<slug:slug>/', ...)` below the other two `path()`s, so that Django matches them first.

Comment: Okay that's working thank you guys

But little question, why i need to move the slug's path below the other two paths? Why it doesn't work?